# How can function accommodate calls passing different objects as parameters?

Tags: javascript, object, variables, parameters, call

I have more than one call to the same function and each call passes a different options object. For example:

```js
function masterStart() {
  A(optionsA);
  A(optionsC);
}
```

I don't know how the code in function `A()` can be written to use each object's passed parameters? If I was only using object `optionsA` I would access them in function `A()` by writing `optionsA.soundFileName`, for example. But what do I do when a second call to `A()` is made that passes parameters from object `optionsC`?

Here is a slimmed down version of my code which isn't able to access parameters from objectC yet:

```js
var optionsA = {
  soundFileName: 'audio/60.wav',
};

var optionsC = {
  soundFileName: 'audio/90.wav',
};

masterStart();

function masterStart() {
  A(optionsA);
  A(optionsC);
}

function A() {
  soundFileName = optionsA.soundFileName;
  console.log('soundFileName: ' + soundFileName)
  // This logs "audio/60.wav" twice instead of "audio/60.wav" and "audio/90.wav"

  // THE REST OF THE CODE THAT PLAYS AND LOOPS THESE SOUNDS SHOULD FOLLOW HERE
}
```

A related question: If both `A()` and `C()` are initialized at the same time, sometimes only one function will run, or sometimes one will execute with the other call's parameters (in my experience) because javascript is single-threaded. Is there a better solution to making them execute accurately than initializing one with a delay (which I am not doing in this code)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
function A(params) {
  soundFileName = params.soundFileName
  // and the rest
}
```

or like this

```
function A({soundFileName}) {
  console.log(soundFileName)
  //...
}
```

Edit: snippet

```js
const optionsA = {
  soundFileName: 'audio/60.wav',
}

const optionsC = {
  soundFileName: 'audio/90.wav',
}

function A(params) {
  console.log("soundFileName: " + params.soundFileName)
}

A(optionsA)
A(optionsC)
```

Comment: How does this allow me to pass `optionsA` and `optionsC` to `A()`? I see you're using `A(params)` but do I need to put the objects `optionsA` and `optionsC` into another object called `params` so they will both pass in?

Comment: no. The way javascript functions work, if you do `function x(a, b, c)` and then call it with `console.log(x(q, w, e))`, then *inside of the function*, `a`, `b`, and `c` get *set* to `q`, `w`, and `e`. If you call it again with `console.log(x(s, d, f))`, then that time `a`, `b`, and `c` get set to `s`, `d`, and `f`. The same works for objects. The second method uses an ES6 method called "destructuring"

Comment: So are you saying there is no solution to my problem? I'm trying to avoid having to make multiple copies of function `A()` since my actual code is much longer.

Comment: there is a solution, you do what I said. Unless i'm not understanding you correctly? I'll update my question with a snippet to try to explain it better (snippet added now)

Comment: I think you're not understanding me. But, I could be wrong. I think you've answered how to pass an object with parameters to a function, which I'm already doing, I believe. What I need is for two different functions that are each calling one function `A()` to be able to use their own unique set of parameters. So I can call `A(optionsA)` and also `A(optionsB)` and have them each use their own parameters inside that same function. I don't think your solution accommodates my need. In particular, I can pass the objects just fine, I just don't know how to code inside `A()` so that it can use both.

Comment: what do you mean that you don't know how to code inside A so that you can use both? I think there's some outside context we're missing; can you explain your particular situation and what exactly you want A to do?

Comment: Inside `A()`, the way I would normally access parameters from `optionsA` would be like this, for example: `optionsA.soundFileName;" But if I need `A()` to be used by `optionsB` also, I couldn't use `optionsA.soundFileName`. So I need `A()` to be able to accept both.

Comment: I also can't just put all the parameters in one object because I need each call, for example, to have it's own unique sound file as a parameter.

Comment: In the A(), you would do `params.soundFileName`, or `params.whateverOptionYouWant`. As long as optionsA and optionsB both have their stuff named the same, it will work

Comment: Ok, interesting. I'll give that a shot and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again and for seeing me questions through. I don't know why I thought the arguments in the calls (`A(optionsA);` and `A(optionsB);`) and the parameters in the called function (specifically in the function definition which I didn't' even include in my example) had to be the same name. I think that's what was tripping me up.